# Flexbox items not growing height to 100%

Tags: css, flexbox

Im following this tutorial from CSS Tricks,

https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/

Where it shows how to have flexboxes where each box, occupies as much as it cans to fill the height of the screen...

MAKE WINDOW LESS THAN 750px  --> http://thisisgiorgio.meteor.com/

I think I have done exactly what he says, but the divs are not occupying the 100% of the screen..

my html:

```
    <div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="home-mob">THIS IS GIORGIO</div>
  <div class="btns-wrapper">


      <div class="home-btn">
        MUSIC
      </div>
      <div class="home-btn">
        WEB
      </div>
      <div class="home-btn">
        GRAPHIC
      </div>
      <div class="home-btn">
        CONTACT
      </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

my sass:

```
    body
  background-color: rgb(5, 10, 37)
  color: white
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'PT Sans Narrow'
  max-width:1280px
  margin: 0 auto
  height: 100%
  font-weight: bold
  @media (max-width: 750px)
    .main-wrapper
      .home-mob
        font-size: 6em
        text-align: center
      .btns-wrapper
        min-height: 100%
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        background: green
        .home-btn
          flex: 1
          font-size: 3em
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column
          justify-content: center
```

Any ideas whats wrong ? thanks!

Link:  http://thisisgiorgio.meteor.com/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/je5286fq/2/ It's not clear what you are trying to do but this might help.

Comment: I don't see that css in your page